# How to replace all \" in a JS string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

How to replace all `\"` to `"` in a string?

I tried, but it doesn't works: `var foobar = ("foo\\\"bar\\\"foo").replace(/"\\\""/,'"');`

The result is `foo\"bar\"foo` , but it should be `foo"bar"foo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use quotes inside of a RegEx pattern, the `//` delimiters act as ones.

```
var foobar = "foo\\\"bar\\\"foo".replace(/\\"/g,'"');
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try `.replace(/\\"/g,'"');` - regexes don't need quotes around them, I'm surprised you get any result at all.

Comment: Well, why not? He is trying to replace something that doesn't exists in original string, so he just gets it back unmodified.

Comment: That's what I meant, but for some reason I didn't type that >_>

Answer (score 5):

You need to fix your regex, you need to do

```
replace(/\\\"/g, "\"")
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: My bad, confused about your multiple slashed there for a minute (Note that you don't need to escape quotes inside of a regex pattern)

Answer (score 3):

Your quoting is wrong and you're not using g - global flag. It should be:

```
var foobar = ("foo\\\"bar\\\"foo").replace(/\\"/g,'"');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try defining it like this

```
var foobar = ("foo\\\"bar\\\"foo").replace(/"\\\""/g,'"');
```

note that the `.replace` has a **`/g`** which makes it global

Comment: This will fail. No quotes around regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/CcjkD/)

```
// initial string
var str = "AAAbbbAAAccc";

// replace here
str = str.replace(/A/g, "Z");
alert(str);
​
```

Comment: Why the down vote on this one? It replaces the "A"s for "Z"s and shows how to use the `replace`...

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: Hover over the downvote icon, "This answer is not useful" yeah, pretty much sums it up for me. While it does show the correct use of `str.replace()` it doesn't, in fact, help in any way to the OP.

Comment: I must admit.  This is a really bad answer to the question.  I must have been half sleeping when I wrote this.  :)